# How to make Lebanese chicken wings

Tags: chicken, chicken-wings

I have been going to a lebanese restaurant for a while now and they do the best chicken wings i have ever tasted. i want to know their secret. they are chargrilled over coal and i know that they put butter on them to help with the browning. what i cant replicate is that they are sticky, the seasoning goes right to the bone and they also manage to get a sort of citrus flavour to the bone also. i imagine that some sort of brine would help with the seasoning going into the flesh but the citrus notes have me stumped. if anyone actually knows a recipe or even just has some suggestions id be very appreciative. thanks.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Recipe requests are off topic here. Everyone has their own favorites and this leads to what can be a never-ending list of recipes. That said, a Google search for 'Lebanese grilled chicken wings' provided many recipes to choose from. We welcome new users and invite you to take our tour and visit our help pages to see how the site works. Both can be found under the question mark (?) dropdown at the top of the page.

Comment: ok thanks. it wasnt actually a recipe i was looking for, more how to achieve the specific characteristics which i mentioned.

Comment: If you've tried other recipes or methods and they aren't getting the result you want, it would help to know the specifics of what you've done so that we can suggest changes or tweaks. One other quick thought is, have you asked the owner or chef of the restaurant about their recipe?

Comment: Most all of the recipes I found used a marinade. The base ingredients in many seem like they would give you what you're looking for or, at the very least, be a good starting point. E.g, most had lemon juice, so there's the citrus. As @logophobe suggests, you can always come back and we can help you tweak your efforts.

Comment: @Cindy : the 'citrus' might also be sumac

Comment: yes all the recipes are very quick to prepare which suggests they have been 'dumbed down'. i just tried them marinated in lots of salt and lemon juice for about 3 hours and they were pretty good. i think perhaps they need at least 24 hour of marinating before they get close to what i have tried in the restaurant. it was this unknown which i was unable to get from recipes on the internet which i was hoping to find here. i fi have more success another time i will post. thanks for all the suggestions.

Comment: I'd ask the restaurant.

Answer (score 2):

Consider asking the people at the restaurant how they do the preparation, since you like it so much, and explain that you are curious to understand how these are different from other varieties of chicken wings.  People who cook professionally are often flattered when people want to understand how they prepare things.  They are unlikely to give you an actual recipe, since restaurant preparations vary greatly from recipes for home cooking, due to process/quantities, etc., but you can learn a lot from asking.

Answer (score 0):

My mothers chicken wing:

for the marinade:

- honey
- Lemon juice
- salt
- paprika
- Lebanese 7 spices
- lots of garlic
- fresh green coriandre leaves
- butter or oil

Let the wings sit in the marinade for few hours, and grill, while rubbing the wings every 2 minutes with the marinade until cooked and golden.

Another recipe is a pot wings:

1. Fry garlic and potato in a frying pan until half cooked, remove and drain fro excess oil.
2. Prepare lots of lemon juice
3. Add the garlic and potatoes to a pan, then add the wings (or any part of the chicken) on top of them.
4. Add the lemon juice until the potatoes and garlic are fully covered.
5. Add a splash of water or chicken broth and bring all to boil until everything is tender and fully cooked.

(You can use the stove or bake them in the oven).

Sahtain.